# Missing document library's description when create a new one based on a list template

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've created a document library (doc lib), added some Columns and Description for the doc lib. Then I saved this doc lib as a list template, and create a new doc lib based on that template. But the new doc lib does not contains any Description at all.

So, does Sharepoint allow us to include Description in a list template, so that a newly created doc lib will also have the description ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No The Title and description is not included when you create a new one from a template. you can store a .stp file with same contents and structure but once when you are creating the library from the template you have to provide a new Title and description. That's why those fields are there at first place.